# Android how to create edit text with single line input and multiline hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am looking to create an edit text with a 3-4 line hint which on click, allows the user to enter only a single line of text. 
I have tried to use

```
android:singleLine = "true"
```

But that limits the length of the hint as well.

How do I assign different number of lines for both ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a TextWatcher to your edit text and compare the length of the text.
If it is 0, then the hint is shown and you programmatically set editText.setSingleLine(false). If it is greater than 0, you restrict the editText with setSingleLine(true).

Pseudocode:

```
    public void some(){
    final EditText t = findViewById(someName);
    t.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            t.setSingleLine(t.getText().toString().length() > 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `textview` property programatically like this :

```
myText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(hasFocus){
        myText.setSingleLine(true);
        //myText.setMaxLines(1);
       // myText.setLines(1);
    }
   else if(myText.matches(""))
   {
      myText.setSingleLine(false);
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="your hint here your hint here your hint here your hint here  your hint here your hint here your hint here your hint here your hint here your hint here "
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```