# 'android:hint' increases height of edittext and never resizes to entered text

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my `EditText` layout:

```
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_information"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
                    android:maxLength="4096"
                    android:hint="@string/default_information"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="11"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:gravity="top"/>
```

`

The problem is that my `default_information` string is very long and occupies four lines. So initially `EditText` is of four lines. But when user tries to enter some text, `EditText` doesn't automatically gets resized up to entered text (for e.g. one line) It remains four lines only.

How to instruct `EditText` to get resized to entered text when hint text is long?

**Update:**

Please see here is GIF demonstrating what problem I am facing:

[image: Please see here is GIF demonstrating what problem I am facing]

Comment: When user starts to enter text, editbox should resize its height to one line and should go on increasing lines as user goes on entering text.

Comment: Yep, and the EditText's box resized within one line when entering text for me, but became scrollable within a single line for more than one line of text input due to the "lines" attribute.

Comment: For me when I start entering text  , default text vanishes as expected but edittext remains four line height as it is.

Comment: Strange. What API version are you using on the device/emulator?

Comment: Tried on Marshmallow as well as on older device (JB) but it exhibits same behavior.

Comment: Dave btw many thanks for your comments (Y) and validations.

Comment: No problem! Here's a GIF of what I experience when using Android Marshmallow with your EditText code: http://giphy.com/go/NzllZTY5OGIt

Comment: Hi Dave, I have updated the question with GIF demo. Also uploaded [here](https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGvhSsMwNR1Iu52/giphy.gif). Please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the # of lines of EditText's hint should be kept one line at most by convention as you usually experience in most if not all apps out there. For instance, it'd be somewhat awkward when you have a large EditText hint that transitions to a single line on initial text input while you have other views rendered around the EditText in your layout, ya know?

Although I believe that's the reason why EditText is designed like that, there's actually an alternative way to hack and configure it the way you want it by using the [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) interface for your EditText programmatically as shown in another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832882/5385758).

P. S. Get rid of the attribute, android:background="@android:color/transparent", just so it'd make your life easier for testing :-)

Comment: Yes exactly I think the behaviour is by design only. I was thinking if user enter multiple lines and deletes them, EditBox automatically resizes to single line. But the same is not true with default entered hint text. Anyways, I finally changed the hint text to single line default text. And put the lengthy text in separate TextView just above this EditBox. Thanks for all your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

For people still searching for a solution to this issue, a decent workaround is to use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) in order to dynamically set/remove the hint. Keep the width and height of your `EditText` at `wrap_content`. The code should look like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                editText.setHint("My hint...");
            } else {
                editText.setHint("");
            }
        }
    });
```

When there is no text, the hint will be set and the `EditText` will resize to the dimensions of the hint. When there is some text, the hint will be empty, and so the `EditText` will have to resize to the dimensions of the actual text.